# Extract a sentence from a text based on another sentence that lacks some words

Tags: php

So, for my university graduation thesis I chose to build a web app that extracts the main idea from an article(summarization app). It's build in PHP.

But I have reached a situation to which I see no possible solutions, maybe you guys can give me an idea or a solution to the problem.

So basically the app relies on extractive algorithms, what I do:
Firstly, I "sanitize" the text, which means I remove all stop words, I stem the words, remove any abbreviation or initials that may contain a '.' that can alter my text from not being broken into sentences correctly.
After that I break the text into sentences by exploding the text by `.` token and I get all sentences in an array.
Now comes the process in which I "give" the sentences a rating, basically this is how I spot the most relevant sentence in the article, the one that has the highest rating is usually the one that contains the article's main idea.

But my problem starts now, the sentences that I have rated are the ones on which I applied all the 'sanitization' and are not in their original form. I want to take the highest rated sentence and based on that I want to extract the original sentence from the text to which this rated sentence matches. I have tried matching it with regex but it doesn't always work. I need a 100% working method that extracts the original sentence from the article based on the highest rated sentence.

I have no idea how to achieve this, since the rated sentence misses words from it. 
I hope you understand my point. Thank you.

EDIT:
This is the function that I now use to match the original sentence in the article but I doesn't always work:

```
private function get_original_sentence($s, $t)
    {
        $s = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $s);
        $s = trim($s);

        $arr = explode(" ",$s);
        $f_word = $arr[0];
        $l_word = $arr[count($arr)-1];

        preg_match('~(?<=\.)([a-zA-Z ]*)'.$f_word.'(.*?)'.$l_word.'([a-zA-Z ]*)(?=\.)~i', $t, $matches);

        if(empty($string))
        {
            preg_match('~(?<=\.)([^\.]*)'.$f_word.'(.*?)'.$l_word.'([^\.]*)(?=\.)~i', $t, $matches);
        }

        return $matches[0] ? $matches[0] : false;
    }
```

The `$s` parameter is the rated sentence after the summarization and `$t` is the full original article.

EDIT 2: The abbreviation removal function, which practicaly sanitizes the whole text not just abbreviations.

```
static private function _remove_abbrev($subject)
    {
        $domains = '\.ro|\.com|\.edu|\.org|\.gov';

        foreach(self::$abrv as $abrv)
        {
            $not.= strtolower(str_replace('.', '\.', $abrv)).'|';
            $not.= strtolower(trim(str_replace('.', '\.', $arbv))).'|';
        }

        $not = substr($not, 0, -1);

        //$subject = preg_replace('~(\".*?\")~u', '', strtolower($subject));//replaces " " from text.
        $subject = preg_replace('~(?<=\.|^)(?![^\.]{60,})[^\.&]*\&[^\.]*\.?~u', '', strtolower($subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('~\b\s?[\dA-za-z\-\.]+('.$domains.')~u', '', strtolower($subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('~\s*\(.*?\)\s*~u', '', strtolower($subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('~\b('.$not.')~u', '', strtolower($subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('~(?<=[^a-z])[A-Za-z]{1,5}+\.[\s\,]*(?=[a-z]|[0-9])~u', '', strtolower($subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('~(?<=[\s\,\.\:])([A-Za-z]*(\.)){2,}+(.)(?=.*)~u', '', strtolower($subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('~(\d)+\.(\d)*(\s)~u', '', strtolower($subject));

        return $subject;
    }
```

This is the abbreviation array collection:

```
static public $abrv = array(
        ' alin.', ' art.', ' A.N.P', ' A.V.A.B', ' A.V.A.S.', ' B.N.R', ' c.', ' C.A.S', ' C.civ.', ' C.com.', ' C.fam.', ' C.pen.', ' C.pr.civ.', ' C.pr.pen', ' C.N.C.D', ' C.N.V.M', ' C.N.S.A.S', ' C.S.M', ' C.S.J', ' D.G.F.P', ' D.G.P.M.B', ' D.N.A', ' D.S.V', 'Ed.', ' etc.', ' H.G.', ' I.G.P.F', ' I.G.P.R', ' I.N.M.L.', ' I.P.J', ' I.C.C.J', ' lit.', ' M.Ap.N.', ' art.', ' M.J.', ' M.Of.', ' nr.', ' O.G.', ' O.U.G.', ' p.', ' P.N.A.', ' par.', ' pct.', ' R.A.A.P.P.S.', ' subl. ns.', ' S.C.', ' S.A.', ' S.P.P.', ' S.R.I.', ' S.R.L.', 'U.N.B.R.', ' urm.', ' str.', ' sec.', ' pag.', ' a.c.', ' dv.', ' dvs.', ' prof.', ' conf.', ' dr.', ' drd.', ' mrd.', ' s.a.m.d'
    );
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok edited the answer with the code.

Comment: Yes i see, now people can help you.

Comment: I guess you should assign the sentences unique ids

Comment: @noreabu yeah, but how ? Before the sanitization I cannot break article into sentences because of the abbreviations and initials in the text (that contain `.` token by which I explode the text), only after I remove those from the article can I break the text into sentences, and if I remove the abbreviation I end up having the sentences that lack words.

Comment: Why doesn't it always work? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: can you post the function, that takes out the abbreviations? maybe you don't have to "take them out" but replace them, with e.g. "incl." -> "\_\_incl\_\_" and based upon that pattern you modify the regexp. I decided for \_ because it needs no escaping for regexp

Comment: @noreabu edited with the function

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

1. You extract all the matches with preg_match_all first into an array with numerical indexes $substitutions
2. Then you replace them with a unique marker utilizing the 4 variable of preg_replace: $count whose value points to the $substitutions array

A rough code sketch:

```
$count = 0;
$substitutions = array();
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    preg_replace($pattern, $subject, '__'.$count.'__', -1, $count);

    foreach ($matches[???] as $match) {
        $substiutions[] = $match;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if i messed up the syntax for referring to $count as call by reference ( e.g. &$ in the documentation).

I think the crux of this approach is to extract the right value from the $matches array. There are some options, how the matches are extracted.  Maybe another approach could be not to use $count from preg_replace but from the according sub-array of $matches

Answer (score 0):

The `_remove_abbr` function doesn't seem to work very well. It removes words like "art" at the end of sentences but doesn't remove abbreviations like "C.A.S." (because it has already removed "c."). It also has at least one typo (`$arbv`) and doesn't define `$not` before concatenating to it.

Nevertheless, how about instead of removing the abbreviations, URLs, and so on, you replace them with space characters? That way, when you split the text into sentences, they would still have the same length as in the original text so you could store the position the sentences start and end at. If necessary, you could convert multiple spaces to a single space at this point but you'd still know where they came from in the original text.

You just need a callback function to achieve this:

```
    $f = function($m){ return str_repeat(" ", strlen($m[0])); };
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=\.|^)(?![^\.]{60,})[^\.&]*\&[^\.]*\.?~u', $f, strtolower($subject));
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~\b\s?[\dA-za-z\-\.]+('.$domains.')~u', $f, $subject);
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~\s*\(.*?\)\s*~u', $f, $subject);
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~\b('.$not.')~u', $f, $subject);
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=[^a-z])[A-Za-z]{1,5}+\.[\s\,]*(?=[a-z]|[0-9])~u', $f, $subject);
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=[\s\,\.\:])([A-Za-z]*(\.)){2,}+(.)(?=.*)~u', $f, $subject);
    $subject = preg_replace_callback('~(\d)+\.(\d)*(\s)~u', $f, $subject);
```